# Algorithms/ library for earthquake prediction using disturbances on TV transmission

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, analytics, data-analysis

It is said that before an earthquake happens, a viewer experiences disturbances in DTH TV transmission in the form of distorted images on the screen which automatically correct after a few seconds.

Is there an algorithm or library already in place which can identify patterns by continuously monitoring TV images? (Asking this so that the same could be tweaked to identify image disturbances instead of writing new ones from scratch).

Comment: Is there some data set that actually shows this? In order to train some classifier to detect this you would need a large dataset that actually shows this to be true.

Comment: And what is the physical explanation for that?

Comment: The idea looks good. Well, in the digital world it is difficult to implement as most of us are using cable TV or DTH service rather than old time analog transmission from TV tower. I would like to add one more thing, not to discourage this question(I liked the idea and will look more) but due to relevance (if you are serious about finding the solution then) have a look in ETWS service provided by 4G cellular.